# Proguard and Cordova via CLI

Tags: cordova, command-line-interface, proguard, cordova-plugin-proguard

It is possible to compile a **Cordova** app with **Proguard** via **CLI**?
How I can do this? Any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: I am also interested in this. Did you figure it out?

Comment: Not yet, If I find an answer I'll post here.

Comment: cordova-proguard-plugin? https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-setup-proguard-in-cordova-application/

Answer (score 1):

For the record:
Here you can find more information about the matter, I hope it helps

https://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/adding-proguard-to-your-android-cordova-project/